# Publish a Query Layer as a Feature Access Service - ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, feature-service, query-layer

I am connecting to a SQL Server 2016 database, and adding data into ArcMap 10.3.1 as a [Query Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/creating-a-query-layer.htm).

I want to publish this data as a [Feature Access](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/windows/what-is-a-feature-service-.htm) service to ArcGIS Server 10.3.1. I have no problems publishing this data as a mapping service. However, when I want to enable Feature Access, I get [00223: Query layer has virtual column](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/00223-query-layer-has-virtual-column.htm) error.

[image]

I have read the documentation on this error, and the only solution is to "Change the query definition of your layer so it no longer contains a virtual column or columns".

I have tried several different ways to alter the sql query (very simple queries), and all still produce this same error.

What is a virtual column? How can I publish a Query Layer as a Feature Access service?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and found out when querying a view, rather select all the fields in the query as opposed to select * from view.